# Curtains.js does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, curtains.js

Here is my project https://c9.io/antibioticvz/demo-project

I tried implement Curtains.js and it's scrolling a page, but I not able to change scrollSpeed: and curtainLinks:

So how to make link to my page part? Who had relevant experiences?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.curtains>li').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.curtains').curtain({
        scrollSpeed: 100,
        curtainLinks: '.curtain-links'
    });
});
```

Comment: I've fixed Links but not scrollSpeed.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason curtains.js doesn't work well with newer versions of jquery. Try using jquery 1.7.